# cprofile on python module

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I am trying to profile a reasonably sized python project using cprofile.

I am usually invoking my python app as a module something like:

```
python -m cabon.apps.detector -i input_image.png
```

Now howo can I use cprofile from the command line. I see that the cProfile itself is invoked as a module with `-m` and how can this be combined with my python app which is also invoked as a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The files `cProfile` and `profile` can also be invoked as a script to profile another script. For example:

> `python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] (-m module | myscript.py)`

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html), we can specify that a module is being profiled by using additional `-m`. First for the `cProfile` and then the actual module:

```
python -m cProfile -m cabon.apps.detector -i input_image.png
```

Comment: Ahhhh damn. I had tried this but mistakenly put the `-m` immediately after the `-s` instead of after the parameter. Thanks!